# Spark: Error on writing DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to write a DataFrame as json format, however an error keeps coming up (it doesn't matter what format I choose):

My code:

```
var finalDF = spark_session.createDataFrame(d, schema)
finalDF.show(10, false)
finalDF.write.mode("overwrite").json("test/df.json")
```

The show method prints the expected result, but when it's about to write it throws this error:

```
    ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonOutputWriter.<init>(JsonFileFormat.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(JsonFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
18/05/16 17:09:48 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\Users\jsolano\IdeaProjects\Test2\test\df.json\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180516170948_0005_m_000000_0\.part-00000-ff4d215c-00f2-4585-89bb-d53426315539-c000.json.crc]: it still exists.
18/05/16 17:09:48 WARN FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir [C:\Users\jsolano\IdeaProjects\Test2\test\df.json\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180516170948_0005_m_000000_0\part-00000-ff4d215c-00f2-4585-89bb-d53426315539-c000.json]: it still exists.
18/05/16 17:09:48 WARN FileOutputCommitter: Could not delete file:/C:/Users/jsolano/IdeaProjects/Test2/test/df.json/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_20180516170948_0005_m_000000_0
18/05/16 17:09:48 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20180516170948_0005 aborted.
18/05/16 17:09:48 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 4)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515: 
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:575)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:478)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:766)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:859)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:842)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:661)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:501)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:482)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:908)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:889)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:786)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStream(CodecStreams.scala:81)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.CodecStreams$.createOutputStreamWriter(CodecStreams.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonOutputWriter.<init>(JsonFileFormat.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JsonFileFormat$$anon$1.newInstance(JsonFileFormat.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.newOutputWriter(FileFormatWriter.scala:305)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$SingleDirectoryWriteTask.execute(FileFormatWriter.scala:314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask$3.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:256)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1375)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:261)
    ... 8 more
```

It doesn't say anything specific.

I'm using Windows 10 with IntelliJ with Scala, I've set the hadoop.home.dir property

Comment: [The solution is not to write in the Users directory. There seems to be a permission problem. So I created a new folder in the C: directory and it works perfect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51609866/6859233) This worked for me when I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

I removed hadoop.dll from hadoop home as mention in below link and it worked for me.

[java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680277/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-c/51681347)

Note: without hadoop.dll error while thrown while writing to COS location.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like on your previous run, the temp folders are not cleaned up. This is known issue. See the link - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12216
Where you able to manually delete the temp folders here C:/Users/jsolano/IdeaProjects/Test2/test/df.json/_temporary?

Comment: No, it doesn't matter if the previous folders were cleaned or not, I've found out that write operations in Spark don't work in Windows 10. I've tested the same script over and over in a Windows 7 machine and worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've found out that Spark write operations don't work in Windows 10. I've ran the script over and over again in Windows 7 and worked perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

The issue will not resolve irrespective of writing into "C:\Users*" or "C:\some_dir"

I think I'm answering the question a bit late but I have resolved this issue by using another method so I thought of sharing it.

1. Download the windows utility for hadoop [winutils](https://osdn.net/projects/win-hadoop/downloads/62852/hadoop-winutils-2.6.0.zip/)
2. Extract the zip file **hadoop-winutils-2.6.0.zip** to **C:\Users\user_name\winutils\bin**
3. In your code set the system property like

```html
System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "C:\\Users\\user_name\\winutils");
```

That's it. Now you can write your dataframe into any windows directory.