# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-spark

I have a Spark project that used to work lately .

the project gets a CSV , and add two fields to it then it outputs with `saveasTextfile()` the content of a *JavaPairRdd*.

my Spark version is : 2.3.0
my java version : 1.8

the project runs in an Eclipse IDE under windows 10.

this is the error :

```
Driver stacktrace:
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2080)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
... 32 more
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

any one knows why i get **suddenly** this error ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I Solved my question :

After that worked for me lately i have put (to run another spark project) in the hadoop home `hadoop.dll` along side to `winutils.exe`.
so i removed `hadoop.dll`and now everything is fine

Comment: you saved my life! :)

Comment: Download link (latest ver worked for me) https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils

Answer (score 3):

I had the same stack trace appear for me, but A.HADDAD's solution didn't work. I solved it by updating my hadoop version (which was 2.6.0) to 2.7.1, as it was closer the hadoop version indicated by my spark instalation (spark-2.3.2-bin-hadoop2.7).

Answer (score 2):

I was getting similar error, realized I had not created the environment variable HADOOP_HOME and Path variable was not updated with HADOOP_HOME\bin