# Scala dataframe export to csv only created a folder

Tags: scala, apache-spark, export-to-csv

I have spark 2.4.0 and I have a dataframe

```
scala> dfExport.show(5)
+--------------+----+---+
|predictedLabel| AAB|AAC|
+--------------+----+---+
|             2|30.0|  1|
|             3|31.1|  2|
|             2|56.0|  1|
|             2|12.0|  3|
|             3|18.0|  2|
+--------------+----+---+
only showing top 5 rows
```

I tried to export it to a csv file with the codes below.

```
scala>dfExport.write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header","true").save("E://...//Output.csv") 
scala>dfExport.write.csv("E://...//Output.csv")
```

It only created a folder with name "Output.csv" under the path and errors below. Am I missing anything?

```
ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 42.0 (TID 45)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
```

Comment: Maybe a duplicate question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680277/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680277/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-c)

Comment: I removed hadoop.dll from hadoop-home directory and restarted spark-shell. It didnt help

Comment: Use Linux. Windows is for other things.

Comment: Am you saying this problem wouldnt appear if I use Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I tried this Java package and it worked. Every row in the dataframe was converted into an array and written into the destination file.

```
import java.io.{File, PrintWriter}

var array=df.collect

val writer = new PrintWriter(new File("E:\\....\\Output.csv" ))

writer.write("AAA,AAB,AAC,AAD"+"\n")

for (i<-0 to array.length-1){
  writer.write(array(i).toString.replace("[","").replace("]","")+"\n")
}

writer.close()
```