# Error while writing spark 3.0 sql dataframe to CSV file using scala without Databricks

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook

I am using the Apache spark 3.0 for the development. I am reading the data from the txt file and after generating the rdd, I am converting into dataframe. My data is huge so I am taking 100 values from the dataframe and generated the new dataframe with the schema. After I am trying to write this as a csv file but I am getting the below Error. Also I filled my null value in the dataframe also. Still haven't got any solution. Please help me into this. I tried every solution over the internet still confusing what to do. I don't want to use databrick here.

My Schema is Below:

````
```
root
 |-- A1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A3: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A4: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- A6: double (nullable = true)
 |-- A7: double (nullable = true)
 |-- A8: double (nullable = true)
 |-- A9: double (nullable = true)
 |-- A10: string (nullable = true)
 |-- A11: string (nullable = true)

```
````

And code which I am using to write csv is below:

````
```
cdf.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header",true).mode("overwrite").save("C:/Users/aksparmar/Documents/test30final.csv")

```

  org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:288)
      ... 36 elided
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0 (TID 102, AKSPARMAR.com, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:560)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
        ... 9 more
    
    Driver stacktrace:
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
      at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
      at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
      at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:195)
      ... 57 more
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
      at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
      at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
      at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
      at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
      ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
      at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
      at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
      at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:560)
      at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
      at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
      at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
      at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
      at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
      ... 9 more
````

Comment: Does this answer your question? [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51680277/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-org-apache-hadoop-io-nativeio-nativeiowindows-c)

Comment: No this is not related to me. I am using jupyter notebook with scala spark shell. Also my HADOOP_HOME is configured properly and winutils.exe also puted in the bin folder. I don't know what is the problem.

Comment: Maybe try "C:\\Users\\aksparmar\\Documents\\test30final.csv" instead of "C:/Users/aksparmar/Documents/test30final.csv".

Comment: Also you can see above error log that several caused which occurred like 
1) Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 8.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 8.0

2) Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

3)Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

Comment: @RudyVerboven I have tried your solution but still same issue.

Comment: @RudyVerboven Please any more help into this problem.

Comment: In order to run the Spark program on windows, you would need Hadoop winutils.exe file as windows don’t support HDFS. Can you please verify that the correct version of Hadoop/winutils is installed.

Comment: @RudyVerboven I have checked correctly, It is the same. I am using spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop3.2 and I also downloaded the same Hadoop 3.2.1 winutils.exe and put it in the bin folder of hadoop

Answer (score 2):

Hadoop.dll file for Hadoop3.2.1 is missing in the bin folder. We require winutil.exe and Hadoop.dll file according to your Hadoop version. Issue resolved.

Comment: u really saved my life, after 2 days of searching !! thanks alot :)